# What is hosts.ics file?

Tags: window, hosts

Sometimes I use the hosts file (`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`), but unexpectedly now I have 2 files *hosts* and *hosts.ics*.
*hosts* seems to be empty and *hosts.ics* looks like:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2001 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This file has been automatically generated for use by Microsoft Internet
# Connection Sharing. It contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names
# for the home network. Please do not make changes to the HOSTS.ICS file.
# Any changes may result in a loss of connectivity between machines on the
# local network.
#

172.24.208.1 somedomain.net
```

Why has Windows (or other software) created *hosts.ics*? Where should I add hosts records? Can I remove *hosts.ics*?